# Check current memory_limit of Replication Server version 15.7.1

Tags: replication, memory, sybase

Does anyone knows how to check the currently `memory_limit` of replication server? I need to increase the `memory_limit` of my replication server, but I couldn't check the current memory limit. Can anyone help?

> W. 2018/03/22 15:58:08. WARNING #7038 SQM(199:0 pds.pdb1) -
>   de/generic/mem/mem.c(2763)
>           WARNING: Memory usage is above 80 percent. Increase 'memory_limit' or reduce cache sizes to avoid repserver threads from
>   sleeping due to lack of memory.
>
> W. 2018/03/22 15:58:53. WARNING #7039 DSI EXEC(199(1) pds.pdb1) -
>   de/generic/mem/mem.c(2763)
>           WARNING CANCEL: Memory usage is below 80 percent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the 'admin config' command to display current configuration settings?

```
admin config, memory_limit
```